# Is it a good way to make design fit for smartphones?

Tags: php, html, css

Is defining width for all objects (inputs, divs etc.) with percentage is a good way for making design fit for smartphones? Or what other way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend you use a less flexible layout, and instead use **[media queries](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/)**. You can specify a set of rules in case the browser window is less than Npx width.

Answer (score 1):

You should check out [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) to help with this.

Comment: Bootstrap is a great example of responsive design. +1.